# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ Android Refrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to POST username, password and get the result from a JSON in Android. But after i clicked the login button i am getting this error.

**Process: com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww, PID: 12957
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $**

AuthorizeSessionModel ;

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.models

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName


data class AuthorizeSessionModel(
    @SerializedName("UserID")
    var UserID: Int,
    @SerializedName("DatePasswordChanged")
    var DatePasswordChanged: String,
    @SerializedName("ForceToChangePassword")
    var ForceToChangePassword: String,
    @SerializedName("LoginType")
    var LoginType: String,
    @SerializedName("UserName")
    var UserName: String,
    @SerializedName("IsActive")
    var IsActive: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("UserFirstName")
    var UserFirstName: String,
    @SerializedName("UserLastName")
    var UserLastName: String,
    @SerializedName("ID")
    var ID: Int
)
```

AuthorizeSessionResponse;

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.models.AuthorizeSessionModel

data class AuthorizeSessionResponse (
    @SerializedName("Value")
    val authorizeSessionModel: AuthorizeSessionModel ,
    @SerializedName("Result")
    val Result : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("Description")
    val Description: String,
    @SerializedName("Code")
    val Code: String
)
```

MyApi ;

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.Field
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface VisaServicesApi {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("index#!/Visa32Services/Session_AuthorizeSession")

suspend fun userLogin(
    @Field("SessionID") SessionID:Int,
    @Field("AuthorityID") AuthorityID: Int,
    @Field("UserName") UserName: String,
    @Field("Password") Password: String,
    @Field("LoginType") LoginType: String
):Response<AuthorizeSessionResponse>

companion object{
operator fun invoke():VisaServicesApi{
    val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build()
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()
return Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .baseUrl("http://bexfatestv2service.saasteknoloji.com/swagger/ui/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
    .create(VisaServicesApi::class.java)

}
}
}
```

AuthorizeSessionRepository;

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.repositories

import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.AuthorizeSessionResponse
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.SafeApiRequest
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.VisaServicesApi

class AuthorizeSessionRepository(
    private val api : VisaServicesApi
):SafeApiRequest(){

suspend fun userLogin(SessionID: Int,AuthorityID: Int,UserName: String,Password : String,LoginType: String):AuthorizeSessionResponse{
return apiRequest { api.userLogin(SessionID, AuthorityID, UserName, Password, LoginType) }

}


}
```

AuthViewModel;

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.auth

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.repositories.AuthorizeSessionRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class AuthViewModel (
    private val repository: AuthorizeSessionRepository
):ViewModel(){

suspend fun userLogin(
SessionID : Int,
AuthorityID: Int,
UserName: String,
Password : String,
LoginType: String
)= withContext(Dispatchers.IO){repository.userLogin(SessionID, AuthorityID, UserName, Password, LoginType)}
}
```

LoginActivity ;

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.auth

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.R
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.util.ApiException
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.util.NoInternetException
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.kodein.di.KodeinAware
import org.kodein.di.android.kodein
import org.kodein.di.generic.instance

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein by kodein()
    private val factory : AuthViewModelFactory by instance<AuthViewModelFactory>()
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityLoginBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel:AuthViewModel




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_login)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,factory).get(AuthViewModel::class.java)

binding.buttonLogin.setOnClickListener{
loginUser()
}
    }
private fun loginUser(){

    val SessionID = 0
    val AuthorityID = 0
    val userName =binding.editTextUsername.text.toString().trim()
    val password = binding.editTextPassword.text.toString().trim()
    val LoginType = "System"

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        try{
val authResponse = viewModel.userLogin(SessionID,AuthorityID,userName,password,LoginType)

            if(authResponse.Result){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Login Successfull!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Login Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }catch (e: ApiException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }catch (e: NoInternetException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


}
}
```

And here my Json response ;

```
{
  "Value": {
    "UserID": 0,
    "DatePasswordChanged": "2020-09-22T07:26:33.654Z",
    "ForceToChangePassword": 0,
    "LoginType": "string",
    "UserName": "string",
    "IsActive": true,
    "UserFirstName": "string",
    "UserLastName": "string",
    "ID": 0
  },
  "Result": true,
  "Description": "string",
  "Code": "string"
}
```

Comment: Do you get the desired response in the log. You can check by filtering for the word http in your log.

Comment: No. I am not getting any response from URL

Comment: Can you check your JSON again are you sure that is the correct schema?

Comment: I realized that my JSON is correct when i run it from swagger. But when i use the POSTMAN to see the response, i am getting codes full of HTML

Comment: @TolgahanTutar url throws error instead of success response . you should check response code in retrofit code

Comment: I solved this problem by changing my BASE URL it was all about that. Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a data class that wraps your `AuthorizeSessionResponse` class.

Something like:

```
data class AuthorizeSessionResponseWrapper (var authorizeSessionResponse: AuthorizeSessionResponse)
```

Comment: Could you explain a liitle bit more like where to put this class. Sorry for asking that but i am new at Android Development

Comment: @TolgahanTutar According to the Response you have posted you won't need to do this

Comment: @AdityaKurkure Okay i see. But still i don't know where is the mistake. I am stuck with it